# Filter create in sequlize used eager loading

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

---

**Problem Statement**

I'm working on a project using Sequelize with a PostgreSQL database, and I'm facing an issue with querying data related to products and their variations.

I have two tables:

1. `Product` table with fields: `id`, `name`, and `category_ids`.
2. `Variation` table with fields: `id`, `product_id`, `frame_color`, and other attributes.

Each product can have multiple variations with different frame colors. I need to write a Sequelize query to achieve the following:

- Retrieve a list of products.
- For each product, include all of its associated variations.
- Optionally, filter the products based on the frame color of their variations.

Here's the Sequelize query I'm using:

```js
// Sequelize query to retrieve products and their variations
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const filterCondition = {
  frame_color: "Red", // Change this condition based on the desired frame color
};

const options = {
  // Your query options go here
  // ...
  include: [
    {
      model: Variation,
      as: "variations_info",
      attributes: [], // Include no variation attributes in the main query
      required: true, // Set required to true to include only products with matching variations
      where: filterCondition, // Condition for filtering products based on frame color
    },
  ],
};
```

However, my current query is not achieving the desired results. It either filters out products without matching variations or doesn't correctly filter variations based on the frame color.

I'm seeking guidance on how to modify the Sequelize query to:

1. Retrieve all products along with all their associated variations.
2. Optionally, filter the products based on the frame color of their variations without excluding any variations.

I appreciate any insights or code examples that can help me achieve this. Thank you!

---

Feel free to use this problem statement as a starting point for your Stack Overflow question, and be sure to include any additional context, code snippets, or specific issues you're facing to get more targeted assistance from the community.

Comment: Seems like you need to use a subquery in the main `where` of `Product` model using `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.literal` and to remove `where` from `include` option

Comment: @Anatoly but I want fetch products which one match with red color from variations so can you please more elaborate for your comment

Answer (score 0):

To filter main `Product` model by `Variation` child model and get all variations for all products as well you need to use a subquery in `Product` conditions using `Sequelize.where` and `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
const products = await product.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(
    Sequilize.literal('(select count(*) from variants where variations.productId=product.id and variations.frame_color=@frameColor)'), '>', 0),
  bind: {
    frameColor: 'Red'
  }
})
```

Here I filtered products that have at least one variation with frame_color='Red'